# 500 server error using IPython notebook on Windows

Tags: python, node.js, ipython, windows-7-x64, jupyter-notebook

I've just done a fresh install of IPython notebook on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

The steps I took were:

1. Install Python 3.4.1 from http://python.org
2. `> pip install ipython[notebook]`
3. `> pip install pywin numpy pygments nodeenv`

I can open a notebook fine.

However, when I select `File > Print Preview` or `File > Download as HTML` I get a 500 server error.

The stack trace is:

```
2014-08-07 09:44:25.431 [NotebookApp] Loaded template full.tpl
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\filters\markdown.py:78: UserWarning: Node.js 0.9.12 or later wasn't found.
Nbconvert will try to use Pandoc instead.
  "Nbconvert will try to use Pandoc instead.")
WARNING:tornado.general:500 GET /nbconvert/html/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb?download=false (::1): nbconvert failed: you need to have pywin32 installed for this to work
ERROR:tornado.access:{
  "Dnt": "1",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36",
  "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb",
  "Host": "localhost:8888",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6",
  "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch"
}
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /nbconvert/html/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb?download=false (::1) 156.01ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 1.00ms referer=None
```

Installing node.js and Pandocs did not help.

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

I've [raised it as an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6283) with the IPython team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) in the end and that worked.

Comment: Still requires to run the ipython as admin

Answer (score 5):

This works:

1. Right-click on the `Command Prompt` in the Start Menu.
2. Select `Run as administrator`.
3. Select `Yes` in the User Account Control dialog.
4. Run `ipython notebook` in the resulting Command Prompt window.

Basically, it has to be run as administrator for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv): `nodeenv (node.js virtual environment) is a tool to create isolated node.js environments.` So after installing nodeenv you need to create new node.js environment: https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv#basic

Comment: Thanks but I tried this, but `nodeenv env` failed with "curl is not recognized..." so I installed curl. Tried again and got "egrep is not recognized...". Where do I get `egrep` for Windows 64 bit from? It seems as though no one uses IPython on Windows.

Comment: I also tried installing Pandoc from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest but it made no difference

Comment: I'm afraid I won't help you:(

Answer (score 0):

This may be an answer for the same error message, but a specific case;

If this error message showed up when executing  in the ipython notebook, re-installing Anaconda3 did not help my case.

Your Python installation, some reasons, may not have installed nbconvert. 
I recommend that you install 'pandoc' that converts all kinds of file formats. It works in the command line mode and through ipython notebook file menu, as well. An easiest way to install pandoc in windows, visit the web site below;

http://www.texts.io/support/0004/

Blessings,
(a debtor)<><