# Jupyter Notebook 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

When I'm trying to download jupyter notebook as anything, I get the 500 Internal Server Error. The traceback is as follows:

```
[E 16:55:32.238 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /nbconvert/html/Notebooks/ya_dash.ipynb?download=true (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/nbconvert/html/Notebooks/dash.ipynb?download=true', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Notebooks/dash.ipynb', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/aleksandr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1443, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/Users/aleksandr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2800, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/aleksandr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbconvert/handlers.py", line 86, in get
        name = model['name']
    KeyError: 'name'
[E 16:55:32.251 NotebookApp] {
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Notebooks/dash.ipynb",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
    }
[E 16:55:32.251 NotebookApp] 500 GET /nbconvert/html/Notebooks/dash.ipynb?download=true (::1) 1229.97ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Notebooks/dash.ipynb
```

When I add "name" key to the model variable, it says that "last_modified" key is missing now. When I add "last_modified" key, it says that there's problem with content. I think the problem is with this line

```
model = self.contents_manager.get(path=path)
```

in handlers.py file of nbconvert library, but I cannot get what it should be instead.

I'm using Python 2.7 on Mac OS X with Anaconda and

jupyter==1.0.0

jupyter-client==4.2.2

jupyter-console==4.1.1

jupyter-core==4.1.0

jupyter-dashboards==0.5.2

jupyterdrive==1.1.0

notebook==4.2.0

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try `conda install notebook` and `jupyter notebook`? After that you should be able to navigate to your notebooks in your browser.

Comment: @DariusM., I have notebook installed. I tried to reinstall it as well, but it did not work.

Comment: Hmm, try to execute the notebook with sudo rights: `sudo jupyter notebook`. Source: [500 server error using IPython notebook on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178602/500-server-error-using-ipython-notebook-on-windows)

Comment: Still keep getting the same error. There seems to be some problem content's path as it cannot capture model. But I can't see what should be the correct one right now.